# Item-level regression coefficients in R?

Tags: r, regression, formulas, coefficients

**Background:**

1000 participants rated their satisfaction with 200 objects (S), as well as providing 4 different psychometric variables (A,B,C,D) about the participant itself. There were 5000 unique objects to rate, thus due to resource constraints, not every participant rated every object. This results in a sparse dataset, where every object was rated by around 30 participants.

From this design, it is trivial to retrieve basic descriptive statistics (e.g. mean satisfaction for each object). My task now is to establish a relationship between psychometric variables (A,B,C,D) and objects - i.e. "What objects will you likely find satisfactory, provided you score a certain way on A,B,C,D?"

The idea is to run a regression, subsequently extracting the mediating coefficients. The formula (and possibly the design) is fairly complex and I have no idea how to even attempt this in R.

**Dataset:**

The dataset is as follows -

[Participant ID] , [Object ID] , [S Rating] , [A] , [B] , [C] , [D]

*The A,B,C,D values are always the same for one particiapant, i.e. they don't depend on the objects. The Object ID ranges from 1 to 5000, with one participant ID being paired with a random selection of 200 objects from the pool of 5000.*

Example:

```
+----------------+-----------+----------+-----+------+------+------+
| Participant ID | Object ID | S Rating | A   | B    | C    | D    |
+----------------+-----------+----------+-----+------+------+------+
| 1              | 23        | 2        | 0.2 | 0.7  | 0.42 | 0.9  |
+----------------+-----------+----------+-----+------+------+------+
| 1              | 69        | 1        | 0.2 | 0.7  | 0.42 | 0.9  |
+----------------+-----------+----------+-----+------+------+------+
| 1              | 769       | 1        | 0.2 | 0.7  | 0.42 | 0.9  |
+----------------+-----------+----------+-----+------+------+------+
| 1              | 1357      | 5        | 0.2 | 0.7  | 0.42 | 0.9  |
+----------------+-----------+----------+-----+------+------+------+
| ... 196 more   |           |          |     |      |      |      |
+----------------+-----------+----------+-----+------+------+------+
| 2              | 84        | 1        | 0.3 | 0.12 | 0.6  | 0.86 |
+----------------+-----------+----------+-----+------+------+------+
| 2              | 345       | 5        | 0.3 | 0.12 | 0.6  | 0.86 |
+----------------+-----------+----------+-----+------+------+------+
| 2              | 1357      | 4        | 0.3 | 0.12 | 0.6  | 0.86 |
+----------------+-----------+----------+-----+------+------+------+
```

**Formula:**

To establish the relationship between item-level object ratings and participant-level psychometric variables, I am hoping to run a regression with the following formula:

S Rating ~ (A + B + C + D) * I + (1/P)

Where S Rating is the S Rating in the dataset, A B C D are psychometric variables from the dataset, I is an item-level coefficient I want to extract, and P is a participant level coefficient.

The formula would offer item-level coefficients - IA, IB, IC, ID for each item (object) in the dataset. This would then answer things like "For object 931, scoring high on A is especially important in predicting satisfaction".

**Questions:**

Is it possible to achieve this in R?

Am I right in thinking that the formula above would give me access to item-level coefficients, allowing me to see how psychometric variables A,B,C,D contribute to predicting S, independently for each item I?

Is it possible to retrieve these coefficients from the regression in R? I am hoping to end up with a table such as : [Object ID] , [Contribution of A] , [Contribution of B] , [Contribution of C] , [Contribution of D]. This would tell the contribution of each psychometric variable to predicting S, for each object separately.

What is the way to go about this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure, you should be able to do that in R. The point is to define the class of you variable correctly. I think I and P should be factors.

And then simply use the lm() function:

obj = lm(Rating ~ (A + B + C + D):I + P)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.
This solution worked great. Properly setting up the factors was the key. I'm only struggling with the size of the dataset now (requires 36GB of RAM), which I've read is possible to overcome using the biglm package, instead of using lm itself.